# portable usb lamp server that runs on linux

Tags: linux

ive found some portable lamp servers like xampp lite but i cant found one that runs on linux, all they are for windows
i need only a lamp server, not a virtual image of a linux system..., i want to run web applications from the usb.

Comment: Linux **is** a lamp server. You install the pieces, you're done.

Answer (score 0):

xampp is not just windows:

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html

Comment: thanks Kerry, i know it but i dont test it because i want to run it on a usb, and it seems that can be tricky, if you know how to do it please tell me...

Comment: I haven't done it myself, so couldn't help you there